# How to determine if an Index is required for my Oracle query

Tags: oracle, indexing

i would like to know if an index is required or would help to run the below query? i dont have any idea how can i analyze this question.

if some one can help please thanks

```
WITH C(A0_ID, A1_ID, A1_Col0) 
AS (
    SELECT 
     
        Table_1.ID AS A0_ID, 
        Table_2.ID AS A1_ID, 
        Table_2.Col0 AS A1_Col0

    FROM Table_1 ,Table_2 

    WHERE Table_2.ID = Table_1.ID 
        AND Table_1.col1 = ? 
        AND BITAND(Table_1.col2, ?) <> ? 
        AND Table_2.col3 IN (?,?,?)

), T(A0_ID, A1_ID, A1_Col0) AS (

    SELECT 
        A0_ID, 
        A1_ID, 
        A1_Col0
    FROM C
    WHERE A1_ID = ?
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        C.A0_ID, 
        C.A1_ID, 
        C.A1_Col0
    from C 
    INNER JOIN T P ON C.A1_Col0 = P.A1_ID

) SELECT A0_ID, A1_ID, A1_Col0 FROM T
```

Comment: I would assume that "indexdb" has nothing to do with this question, since it's a browser-based datastore.

Comment: Formally speaking, indexes are not required in any query. They do improve query performance.

Comment: yes, sorry its mistakes, i removed it.

Comment: @TheImpaler exactly, i would like to know if an index is required for this query ?

Comment: @satcha, It's up to the user running this query. I f this query is taking too much time than expected, You must consider having an index on Table_1(ID, col1), and Table_2(ID, col3).

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, great i will try with this two indexes thanks a lot

Comment: Just keep in mind that every index you add will degrade the performance of all INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE on the table because such actions will require updating the indexes as well as the table itself.   Only real world experience will reveal if the trade-off is worth it.  Is the performance of the SELECT acceptable without the indexes?  Are you coming down with a case of [Compulsive Tuning Disorder](https://oracle-base.com/blog/2009/05/29/compulsive-tuning-disorder/)

Comment: @EdStevens Indexes can also improve the performance of UPDATE and DELETE statements when searching by [unique] indexes, and for INSERT too in the presence of constraint checks that can become much faster.

Comment: @TheImpaler - check constraints are not implemented via indexes, so 'no' on that one.  While an index _may_ (or may not) improve _locating_ a row to be updated, it will _always_ then require the additional I/O of updating all indexes that include updated columns.  And it will _always_ require additional I/O of updating _all_ indexes on any INSERT.  Indexes are not a universal panacea - far from it.

Answer (score 1):

The main query selects from `T` with no post-processing (filtering, aggregation, sorting, etc.), so it doesn't require optimization.

`T` is a recursive CTE based on the subquery `C`. Therefore, `T` doesn't need optimization (unless you materialized it, but that's a different story).

Now, `C` can be optimized:

- I would consider `Table_1` as the driving table since it has an equality in the filtering criteria. It also, uses `ID` to join against `Table_2`. Therefore a good index for it is:

  ```
    create index ix1 on Table_1 (col1, ID);
  ```
- Then, to access `Table_2` you'll need to get through `ID` that should be the main index column. You may add `col3` to the index to somewhat improve the performance of the query; only a benchmark will tell if this is a wise idea. The index could look like:

  ```
    create index ix2 on Table_2 (ID, col3); -- col3 is optional here
  ```

I would recommend you create these indexes and compare the performance that each option produces.

Comment: thanks a lot for this information, i ll create these indexes thanks